# Is there a way to make Internet Explorer 9 always prompt for download location?

Tags: download, internet-explorer-9

Almost every time I download a file, I want to specify where it goes. The default IE9 **Save** button doesn't ask. Instead, I have to click the drop-down arrow next to it, then choose **Save as**.

Is there a way to make **Save as** the default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a Microsoft forum post, *[Internet Explorer 9 set default download action: Save As](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/internet-explorer-9-set-default-download-action/176798a0-94b5-4d0c-8915-a9a41c3df088)*, this option is not available... It seems quite rudimentary, but they removed this capability. The best you can do is change the default location to somewhere you'll easily get to and move files around.

To change the default location (I changed it to my desktop, the easiest location), select menu *Tools* -> *View Downloads* -> *Options* and
change the location.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to partially avoid this problem is to not left-click the file/link that should be downloaded, but instead to right-click it and choose "Save target as...".

Since all the required clicking is right at your cursor, it is, in my opinion, more effective and less annoying than always choosing the option from the popping up, yellow, information bar.

Comment: Yes, but this may only be available on Windows 8 if "Open Internet Explorer tiles on the desktop" is checked (Control Panels -> "Internet Options" -> tab "Programs").

Answer (score -1):

When MS does not care about basic customer request, you need to imagine some woarkaround, e.g.:

1. plug e.g. USB stick in
2. select menu Tools -> View Downloads -> Options and change the location to that drive
3. unplug the USB stick

You are all set: As long as you do not plug the drive, it will always prompt you for a location!

You can go further to avoid saving the attachment to the stick accidentally, change the letter of the stick e.g. to Z:, select Z: in the option and change the letter back to "normal" D: or E:

Or the geek way: find the option in registry and edit manually!

Regards,
Gauthier